# MVC 5.2 EditorFor HtmlAttributes Stopped Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm not sure what changed but the htmlAttributes on my EditorFor helpers all of sudden stopped working. The labels still work, but not EditorFor. If I change them to TextBoxFor the attributes / classes are added.

Classes not added:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "textboxXXLg k-textbox" } })
```

Classes are added:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label ctrl-label required" })
```

I verified I'm using MVC 5.2.

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out. I added the default Kendo Editor Templates and they were conflicting with the EditorFor. Not sure why, I didn't have time to figure it out. Once I removed the Kendo Templates they stared working again.

Comment: Thank you, I was about to go crazy.  Now I can move on knowing at least why it's not working.

Comment: now question is how to fix this conflict proper way.

Comment: What I end up doing is to rename Kendo's editor templates to something like nameKendo.cshtml (for example StringKendo.schtml) and all is working OK. If I really need kendo template then I use UIHint attribute on the model property poiting to Kendo Template. By this trick (renaming) we can avoid conflict. 
Any comments?